# Short code keys for special language characters

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard, language, special-characters

So I am on Windows XP 64-bit and I don't know what I did at install but it's pretty nice.

I can do:

```
~n ~a ~o for ñ ã õ
'o for ó
"o for ö
`o for ò
^o for ô
```

etcetc.  But how did this feature get enabled and how to enable it for other windows installs.  Also is there some short code for the upside down punctuation marks: ? !

thanks for share

Comment: What language(s) did you install?  What keyboard layout are you using? What language is the keyboard intended for (ie: is it a French-Canadian keyboard, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using the US International keyboard layout, rather than the basic US layout. The former uses the <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd> and <kbd>~</kbd> keys as [dead keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key), allowing you to combine them with letters to produce characters with diacritics.

See the images below (courtesy of Wikipedia) for the differences between the two layouts.

US basic:
[image: US basic keyboard layout]

US International:
[image: US International keyboard layout]

As you can see, with the international layout you can use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd> for `¿` and `¡`, respectively.

Another option, if you have a numeric keypad, is to use [Alt codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_codes) (holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and typing in a numeric sequence on the numpad. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0191</kbd> produces `¿` and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0161</kbd> produces `¡`. See [here](http://alt-codes.org/list/) for a full list of Alt codes.

Finally, you can download [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22339), create your own custom layout and map those symbols to any key combination you want.